# Save Changes to a Vim Buffer Without Switching to That Buffer

Tags: vim

How can I save the changes to a modified Vim buffer without switching to that buffer? I am trying to write a function that saves and closes all the buffers in a project.

Comment: Why the requirement to avoid switching to the buffer?

Comment: @DonReba It's cleaner and faster-- when you switch to the buffer it triggers autocmds etc; also if you are doing this within a function then there is extra coded needed to store your original buffer so that you can switch back to it at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the `:wqall` command, there's no command that writes a buffer other than the current one.

So you do have to switch to the buffer in order to write it. You could use `:noautocmd` to avoid the associated events (but that may have adverse side effects!).

The only alternative would be to use low-level functions like `getbufline()` and `writefile()`, but then you would have to deal with encoding conversions, fileformat, etc. on your own.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:wqa[ll]`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#%3awqall) to write and close all changed buffers.  `:wa` will write without closing.

Comment: `:x` is like `:wq`, except it writes only those buffers that have changed.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to write all buffers, only a specified set (e.g. the ones inside a particular project). Is there a way?

Comment: @SeanMackesey, "I am trying to write a function that saves and closes **all** the buffers in a project."

Answer (score 1):

You can use the argument list, see `:help argument-list`.

Supposing you are working with three files `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, and want to only write `foo` and `baz`:

```
:args foo baz
:argdo w
```

You'll obviously need additional logic to determine which buffers to put in the arglist in the first place but it sounds like you already have that.

Comment: That still switches to each buffer, and also doesn't keep the original buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a buffer without having it in the foreground. However, if you save the buffer number of the foreground buffer, you can restore the foreground buffer after writing the hidden buffer. The screen shouldn't even flicker:

```
let c=bufnr()|let b=bufnr($MYVIMRC)|if b!=-1|exe "b" b|w|exe "b" c|endif
```

May fail if :set hidden isn't enabled.

From my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <Leader>r :call WriteBufIfOpen($MYVIMRC) \| source $MYVIMRC<CR> 

func! WriteBufIfOpen(file)
    let c = bufnr('')
    let b = bufnr(a:file)
    if (b != -1)
        exe b."bufdo w"
        exe "b" c 
    endif
endfunc
```